# python pass long running process to another script

Tags: python, process

I am trying to run two python scripts, script1 calls script2, script2 is a long running process which passes stuff back to script1 in realtime.

Here is script1:

```
from script2 import Test2

model_info = Test2()
info = model_info.test2_run()

print info
```

Here is script2:

```
class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        print("running")

    def test2_run(self):
        a = 100000
        for line in range(a):
            return line
```

How do I get script2 to constantly feed `line` back to script1?

Comment: Here, script1 and script2 are not running as independent, separate processes in your computer.  For that, you need something like `fork()` or the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Your script 2 throws an exception if actually run. `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: You will have to use either the threading or the multiprocessing module. Using two separate scripts here is pointless.

Comment: This is just an example of what I would like to do, I know this is pointless.

Comment: Sorry Paul, I have fixed the script so it now runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given below are the four different ways to achieve this. Say you have two python scripts, `producer.py` and `consumer.py` as given below.

**producer.py**

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
range_limit = 3

class LineProducer(object):    
    def __init__(self, msg = ''):
        print(self.prepare_line('Initializing %s%s' % (self.__class__.__name__, msg)))

    def prepare_line(self, line):
        return '%d - %d : %s' % (multiprocessing.current_process().pid, threading.current_thread().ident, line)

    def run(self):
        for line in range(range_limit):
            yield self.prepare_line(line)


class MultiThreadedLineProducer(LineProducer):
    def produce(self, q):        
        for line in range(range_limit):
            q.put(self.prepare_line(line))

        q.put(None)

    def run(self):
        q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        threading.Thread(target = self.produce, args = (q,)).start()

        while 1:
            line = q.get(True)

            if line == None:
                break;

            yield line

class MultiProcessedLineProducer(LineProducer):
    def produce(self, q):        
        for line in range(range_limit):
            q.put(self.prepare_line(line))

        q.put(None)

    def run(self):
        q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        multiprocessing.Process(target = self.produce, args=(q,)).start()

        while 1:
            line = q.get(True)

            if line == None:
                break;

            yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for line in LineProducer(' inside a separate process').run():
        print(line)
```

**consumer.py**

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from producer import LineProducer, MultiThreadedLineProducer, MultiProcessedLineProducer

#using normal yield
for line in LineProducer().run():
    sys.stdout.write(line + '\n')

#using yield with multi threading
for line in MultiThreadedLineProducer().run():
    sys.stdout.write(line + '\n')

#using yield with mult processing
for line in MultiProcessedLineProducer().run():
    sys.stdout.write(line + '\n')

#using normal yield in child process
for line in Popen(['python', 'producer.py'], bufsize = 0, shell = False, stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT).stdout:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Now if you execute `python consumer.py`, it will produce an output similar to the one given below

```
8834 - 140419442169664 : Initializing LineProducer
8834 - 140419442169664 : 0
8834 - 140419442169664 : 1
8834 - 140419442169664 : 2
8834 - 140419442169664 : Initializing MultiThreadedLineProducer
8834 - 140419409151744 : 0
8834 - 140419409151744 : 1
8834 - 140419409151744 : 2
8834 - 140419442169664 : Initializing MultiProcessedLineProducer
8837 - 140419442169664 : 0
8837 - 140419442169664 : 1
8837 - 140419442169664 : 2
8839 - 140280258066240 : Initializing LineProducer inside a separate process
8839 - 140280258066240 : 0
8839 - 140280258066240 : 1
8839 - 140280258066240 : 2
```

The output format is `PID - ThreadID : Message`, where `PID` is the process id and `ThreadID` is the thread identifier from where the `Message` is generated.

Now you can see that, the first set of output has PID and ThreadID same for all the lines. Here the supply is based on the demand, i.e an output line is produced when the consumer asks for it.

In the second set, PID remains same, but has different ThreadID for the lines generated. Thats because, the producer and consumer runs in different thread. And the lines are produced regardless of consumer demand. A thread in Python uses native threads, like pthread, but because of Global Interpreter Lock, no two threads can run at same time, that means you wont get the parallelism in the true sense.

Now, coming to the third set, PID is different, which means the consumer runs in a different process which is forked from the current process. This enables true parallelism and can utilize multiple CPU cores effectively. As with multi threads, this also produce lines regardless of the consumer demand.

Multi threading and multi processing uses queue to communicate between threads/processes. You may limit the production of lines by specifying the number of items while creating the queue. In this way, lines are produced till the queue becomes full. The production resumes as the lines are consumed from the queue.

Now, the last set, it uses fork/exec mechanism to create a process and replace the image with executable specified. It is same as the first set, but with different PID and ThreadID. The difference in this method and the third method is that you cannot use a queue to communicate between processes, and relies on pipes and other IPC mechanisms. Also, the `producer.py` should be an executable python script. In this case also, lines are produced regardless of the demand from consumers.

Comment: Perfect answer, worked well for my problem, thank you.

Comment: Hi Vishal, could you give me an example of the parallel processing please?

Comment: @speedyrazor, I have updated the answer with parallel processing.

Comment: Hi Vishal, thats great, thanks for that, would that work for my other problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957353/python-3-4-urllib-request-download-file-pass-percentage-to-another-script